# How can I set a image to an div by JS (or jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a notification box like this:

[image]

As you see, there is an image `.gif` on the top of it which will be hide when the content loads. Now I want to add following image to a `<div>`:

[image]

Here is my ajax code:

```
function notification(){

    $(".notifications_list").html(/* add this path: /myfolder/img/progress.gif */ );

    $.ajax({
        url :  '/myweb/files/notification.php',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (notification_system) {

            $(".notifications_list").html(/* remove progress.gif photo */ );

            if(notification_system.success === 1){  
                $(".notifications_list").html(notification_system.notifications);

            } else {
                alert('something is wrong');                            
            }

        }
    }); 

}
```

Please focus on these two lines:

```
$(".notifications_list").html(/* add this path: /myfolder/img/progress.gif */ );

$(".notifications_list").html(/* remove progress.gif photo */ );
```

How can I do that? I mean, how can I add an image by its path to the HTML and then remove it?

Comment: You could prepend the image to the container div and give the image a custom css class/id. When you want to remove it, just remove that class/id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'prepend' and 'remove'...

```
 $('.notifications_list').prepend('<img class="your_image" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">')
```

and to remove

```
$('.notifications_list .your_image').remove();
```

[Demo here...](https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/4vr355su/1/)

Comment: @MartinAJ No problem... mark the answer as correct if it works for you. It'll help other people find the answer when they have the same problem.